# SQL server DB mailbox can not send mail

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I just desire to create below trigger when it take effect, then execute db mailbox to sendout one email to specific person which is configured in the profile. and after completed the configuration, just send one test email via right click the 'Database Mail', i can receive the test mail. but after i make the trigger works, it reminds me 'mail`id:10` in queue', then my mailbox never receive any mails. and there's no exception or error at all but no mail incoming. and i can confirm that the profile configuration is correction enough on SMTP,ACCOUNT,PASSWORD. so worried on this, can anybody give me a hand on this? really appreciate on this!

1. I have been tried to send the test mail via right click sqlserver management - database mail - sent test mail, it works for me.
2. i have been tried to restart the service of all sql server, but no response.
3. i have been tried to see the queue via EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type ='Mail';and there shows me length = 0,status= RECEIVES_OCCURRING.
4. I have been tried to reconfigured the profile but no response.
   i expecting after th trigger which i write in SQLserver works, then it can execute the command and trigger the db mailbox to send out relate mail accordingly.

```sql
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name='henryTest',
  @recipients='henry@xxx',
  @subject='serial range exception!!!',
  @body='serial range exception!!!',
  @body_format='text'.
```

Comment: SMTP mail is a complex environment and definitely falls into the "not guaranteed delivery" category due to registration requirements like SPF, DKIM and DMARC. Have you tried querying SQL Server's `sysmail_event_log` to see if the databasemail.exe send process recorded any error messages? Do you have access to the `/var/log/maillog` files on the receiving SMTP mail server (assuming it's Linux-based) to see if the messages got rejected for any particular reason?

Comment: Yes ,sure I also try to see the log of sysmail_event_log , there’s no response log after my trigger works and ‘mail id=10 queued’ printed. And also try to manually run database mail.exe under administrator access but still not work.  I don’t have access to check from company’ s SMTP server side but maybe it’s a good idea to find something. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this issue has been fixed quite days ago, through `SMTP` correct correction on server side. Advice from me is first you should check your server /PC whether not open/support `SMTP`, then try others.